# Why is my INNER JOIN so slow? Server times out

Tags: mysql, sql

my relatively simple query is taking so long to execute that the server times out.  Incidentally, if I run the sub-query on it's own, it executes very quickly.

Essentially I'm trying to get the first date for each game_id, then get the corresponding score and duration...

My query:

```
SELECT 
    sq.*, 
    up.score AS score, 
    up.duration AS duration 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        up.uid AS uid, 
        up.lesson_id AS lesson_id, 
        up.level AS level, 
        up.game_id AS game_id, 
        MIN(up.date) AS first_date
    FROM cdu_user_progress up
    WHERE (up.score >= '0') 
    GROUP BY up.uid, up.lesson_id, up.level, up.game_id
) sq
INNER JOIN cdu_user_progress up ON up.uid = sq.uid AND up.lesson_id = sq.lesson_id AND up.level = sq.level AND up.game_id = sq.game_id AND up.date = sq.first_date
GROUP BY sq.uid, sq.lesson_id, sq.level, sq.game_id
```

cdu_user_progress is:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|id    |uid    |lesson_id    |game_id    |level    |score    |duration    |date    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Explain:

```
Field      Type     Null    Key     Default     Extra
--------------------------------------------------------------
id         int(11)  NO      PRI     NULL        auto_increment
uid        int(11)  NO      NULL     
lesson_id  int(11)  NO      NULL     
game_id    int(11)  NO      NULL     
level      int(11)  NO      NULL     
score      int(11)  NO      NULL     
duration   int(11)  NO      NULL     
date       int(11)  NO      NULL
```

Comment: This article might help you: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think you need the outer `group by`, unless you have duplicates by date.  If so, perhaps you can use `id` instead of or in addition to `date`:

```
SELECT sq.*, up.score AS score,  up.duration AS duration 
FROM (SELECT up.uid, up.lesson_id, up.level, up.game_id,
             MIN(up.date) AS first_date
      FROM cdu_user_progress up
      WHERE up.score >= 0 
      GROUP BY up.uid, up.lesson_id, up.level, up.game_id
      ) s INNER JOIN
      cdu_user_progress up
      ON up.uid = sq.uid AND up.lesson_id = sq.lesson_id AND
         up.level = sq.level AND up.game_id = sq.game_id AND
         up.date = sq.first_date;
```

The best indexes for this query are `cdu_user_progress(score)` and `cdu_user_progress(uid, lesson_id, level, game_id, date)`.  If the first query runs fast, the second index should be a big help.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by indexes... The revised query you gave is the same as my original one (without the outer group bys)?

Comment: @SimonLobo-Morell . . . Indexes are an important way to improve performance on databases.  You should learn about them:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization-indexes.html.